# Nuxt 2.x: Add babel's transform plugin, that work on imported node_module file

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, nuxt.js

How to add `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining` plugin to `.nuxt.config` that work for a file imported from `node_modules` (a one that not pre-build )

By this Example [here](http://Follow%20by%20that%20example:) I do:

```
export default {
  plugins: [
        '~/plugins/accesso.js' // that one make the trouble
  ],
  build: {
   babel: {
     plugins: [
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining', {loose: true}]
     ]
   }
 }
}
```

```js
// ~/plugins/accesso.js
import Accesso from '@perymimon/accesso'

export default function (ctx, inject) {
    inject('Accesso', accesso)
}
```

And it works fine for some `foo?.bar` in `.vue` files but not for files that come from `node_module`.

why?

The eror is reguar error from webpack

```js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (311:25)                                                                                                                                                 friendly-errors 14:39:06
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| function frame$extractPayload(frame, authSetting) {
>     let location = frame?.contentWindow?.location || frame.location;
|     const {protocol, host, pathname} = location;
|     const atHome = protocol + '//' + host + pathname === authSetting.redirect_uri;
                                                                                                                                                                                               friendly-errors 14:39:06
 @ ./node_modules/@perymimon/accesso/src/providers.js 1:0-37 3:0-29 3:0-29 8:22-29 34:23-30 51:22-29
 @ ./plugins/accesso.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi eventsource-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&name=modern&path=/__webpack_hmr/modern ./.nuxt/client.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm speculating that it may be that the dependencies in question are not already transpiled.

In `vue.config.js` you can specify an array of dependencies that should be transpiled by the project.

`vue.config.js:`

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ['tomsNodeModule'],
}
```